# Spark Dataframe transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- eventTimestamp: long 
 |-- trackingId: string 
 |-- voyageStatus: string
```

Here are some sample rows:

```
+--------------+----------+------------+
|eventTimestamp|trackingId|voyageStatus|
+--------------+----------+------------+
|          504 |78911c81  |COMPLETE    |
|          504 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |
|          390 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |
|          390 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |
|          349 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |
|          349 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |
|          349 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |
|          350 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |
|          350 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |
|          350 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |
|          351 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |
|          351 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |
|          351 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |
|          352 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |
|          352 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |
|          352 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |
|          507 |3b77a150  |COMPLETE    |
|          349 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |
|          349 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |
|          349 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |
+--------------+----------+------------+
```

I want to add a new column of type long called `completionEventTimestamp`.  For each row, this column will have the following value:

1. If there is a record with the same `trackingId` as the current row with the value of `voyageStatus` equal to `"COMPLETE"`, then the value will be the `eventTimestamp` of that record.
2. Otherwise, the value will be -1 (so the row can be filtered out later).

Here is what the transformation would yield for the example above:

```
+--------------+----------+------------+------------------------+
|eventTimestamp|trackingId|voyageStatus|completionEventTimestamp|
+--------------+----------+------------+------------------------+
|          504 |78911c81  |COMPLETE    |                     504|
|          504 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |                     507|
|          390 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |                      -1|
|          390 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |                     504|
|          349 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |                     507|
|          349 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |                      -1|
|          349 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |                     504|
|          350 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |                     507|
|          350 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |                      -1|
|          350 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |                     504|
|          351 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |                     507|
|          351 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |                      -1|
|          351 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |                     504|
|          352 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |                     507|
|          352 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |                      -1|
|          352 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |                     504|
|          507 |3b77a150  |COMPLETE    |                     507|
|          349 |ece6c8d0  |ACTIVE      |                      -1|
|          349 |78911c81  |ACTIVE      |                     504|
|          349 |3b77a150  |ACTIVE      |                     507|
+--------------+----------+------------+------------------------+
```

If this helps at all, if a record with a given `trackingId` has a `voyageStatus` of `"COMPLETE"`, then it will be the last such record with that `trackingId` (if you were to order by `eventTimestamp`), and there will only be one such record.

Answer (score 0):

```
val completedVoyagesDF = training3.filter(training3("voyageStatus") === "COMPLETED").select("trackingID", "statusTimestamp")
val completedVoyagesArray = completedVoyagesDF.collect().map({
  row: Row => row.getString(0) -> row.getLong(1)
})
val trackingIDToActualArrivalTime = completedVoyagesArray.toMap

val arrivalTime: (String => Long) = (trackingId: String) => {
  trackingIDToActualArrivalTime.getOrElse(trackingId, -1)
}
val arrivalTimeFunc = udf(arrivalTime)
val withActualArrivalTimeDF = training3.withColumn(LABEL_COL_NAME, arrivalTimeFunc(col("trackingId")))
val training4 = withActualArrivalTimeDF.filter(withActualArrivalTimeDF(LABEL_COL_NAME) =!= -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect_list` over `window` partitions to save the status list per `trackingId` and a `UDF` to conditionally assign value to`completionEventTimestamp` as shown below:

```
val df = Seq(
  (504L, 10, "ACTIVE"),
  (506L, 10, "ACTIVE"),
  (510L, 10, "COMPLETE"),
  (390L, 11, "ACTIVE"),
  (395L, 11, "ACTIVE"),
  (398L, 11, "ACTIVE"),
  (352L, 12, "ACTIVE"),
  (360L, 12, "COMPLETE")
).toDF("eventTimestamp", "trackingId", "voyageStatus")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// Save "completeTimestamp" for every row with COMPLETE status
val df2 = df.select(
  $"eventTimestamp".as("completeTimestamp"), $"trackingId"
).where(df("voyageStatus") === "COMPLETE")

// Create a "statusList" per "trackingId" for each row using collect_list over window partitions
val window = Window.partitionBy("trackingId")
val df3 = df.withColumn("statusList", collect_list("voyageStatus").over(window))

// A UDF to check whether statusList contains "COMPLETE"
val checkComplete = udf(
  (l: Seq[String]) => l.contains("COMPLETE")
)

// Join df3 with df2 and apply the UDF to assemble "completionEventTimestamp"
val df4 = df3.join(df2, Seq("trackingId"), "left_outer").
  withColumn(
    "completionEventTimestamp",
    when(checkComplete($"statusList"), $"completeTimestamp").otherwise(-1L)
  ).select(
    "eventTimestamp", "trackingId", "voyageStatus", "completionEventTimestamp"
  )

df4.show
+--------------+----------+------------+------------------------+
|eventTimestamp|trackingId|voyageStatus|completionEventTimestamp|
+--------------+----------+------------+------------------------+
|           352|        12|      ACTIVE|                     360|
|           360|        12|    COMPLETE|                     360|
|           504|        10|      ACTIVE|                     510|
|           506|        10|      ACTIVE|                     510|
|           510|        10|    COMPLETE|                     510|
|           390|        11|      ACTIVE|                      -1|
|           395|        11|      ACTIVE|                      -1|
|           398|        11|      ACTIVE|                      -1|
+--------------+----------+------------+------------------------+
```